# How to do a cute DIV radius

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have a cute radius div on top-right and top-left.
I tried simply with :

```
border-top-left-radius: 5em;
border-top-right-radius: 5em;
```

Desired div radius
[image: Desired div radius]

Actual div radius
[image: Actual div radius]

EDIT

```
.picker-map {
  border-top-left-radius: 5em;
  border-top-right-radius: 5em;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 7px dashed;
  border-top-color: #FC5241;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Maybe you can draw it as an svg, or on a canvas?

Comment: .picker-map {
    border-top-left-radius: 5em;
    border-top-right-radius: 5em;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 7px dashed;
    border-top-color: #FC5241;
}

Comment: Did you try changing the value you gave to the radius? Or did you guess 5em was right and just left it?

Comment: I choose 5em...

Comment: @AlexisGiuseppe That doesn't create an arc along the top edge.

Comment: It looks like they want the top to be curved.

Comment: Oh ! I'm so noob... i find that border-*-radius can receive 2 parameters.

Comment: border-top-left-radius: 100px 50px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px 50px;

Comment: @AlexisGiuseppe That still doesn't create the long, sweeping arc along the top border.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, but you have to catch right positioning and sizies:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Nice solution! ;)

Answer (score 2):

The desired shape seems to be not achievable with a single border radius. But you can combine two shapes with different border radius, like this:

```css
div {
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px 20px 0;
}

div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  top: -14px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 100% 100% 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to need to have two elements within a parent:

One that has a very large width to create the long, sweeping arc.
One that overlaps that with rounded corners

Then, add a little CSS magic.

```css
.container {
  width:500px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.back {
  width:1000px;
  height:500px;
  background-color:aliceblue;
  border-radius:500px 500px 0 0;
  transform:rotate(49deg) translate(50px, 125px);  
}

.front {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  position:absolute;
  top:90px;
  border-radius:50px;
  background-color:aliceblue;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="back"></div>
  <div class="front"></div>
</div>
```